# When is the default cache stored off-heap in Apache Ignite 2.0

Tags: c++, ignite

This configuration is **not valid in 2.0** version

```
<!-- Enable off-heap storage with unlimited size. -->
<property name="offHeapMaxMemory" value="0"/>
```

Error:

```
    WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
 Error creating bean with name 'grid.cfg' defined in URL [file:/home/ignite/sample-cache.xml]: Cannot create inner bean
 'org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration#4cc0edeb' of type  [org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration] while setting bean
  property 'cacheConfiguration' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with
  name 'org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration#4cc0edeb' defined in URL [file:/home/ignite/sample-cache.xml]: Error setting property
  values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'offHeapMaxMemory' of bean class
 [org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration]: Bean property 'offHeapMaxMemory' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the
 parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
```

Visor SnapShot

```
Time of the snapshot: 07/07/17, 16:54:35
+===========================================================================================================================+
|    Name(@)    |    Mode     | Nodes |      Entries (Heap / Off-heap)      |   Hits    |  Misses   |   Reads   |  Writes   |
+===========================================================================================================================+
| txnCache(@c0) | PARTITIONED | 1     | min: 2917681 (2917681 / 0)          | min: 0    | min: 0    | min: 0    | min: 0    |
|               |             |       | avg: 2917681.00 (2917681.00 / 0.00) | avg: 0.00 | avg: 0.00 | avg: 0.00 | avg: 0.00 |
|               |             |       | max: 2917681 (2917681 / 0)          | max: 0    | max: 0    | max: 0    | max: 0    |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

Cache 'txnCache(@c0)':
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| Name(@)                     | txnCache(@c0)                  |
| Nodes                       | 1                              |
| Total size Min/Avg/Max      | 2917681 / 2917681.00 / 2917681 |
|   Heap size Min/Avg/Max     | 2917681 / 2917681.00 / 2917681 |
|   Off-heap size Min/Avg/Max | 0 / 0.00 / 0                   |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+

Nodes for: txnCache(@c0)
+============================================================================================================+
|     Node ID8(@), IP      | CPUs | Heap Used | CPU Load |   Up Time    |         Size         | Hi/Mi/Rd/Wr |
+============================================================================================================+
| 924C5A56(@n0), 10.0.2.55 | 2    | 8.93 %    | 93.83 %  | 00:12:31:969 | Total: 2917681       | Hi: 0       |
|                          |      |           |          |              |   Heap: 2917681      | Mi: 0       |
|                          |      |           |          |              |   Off-Heap: 0        | Rd: 0       |
|                          |      |           |          |              |   Off-Heap Memory: 0 | Wr: 0       |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
'Hi' - Number of cache hits.
'Mi' - Number of cache misses.
'Rd' - number of cache reads.
'Wr' - Number of cache writes.

Aggregated queries metrics:
  Minimum execution time: 00:00:00:000
  Maximum execution time: 00:00:00:000
  Average execution time: 00:00:00:000
  Total number of executions: 0
  Total number of failures:   0
```

Visor snapshot shows **Off-Heap/Off-Heap-Memory as 0**. In Documentation, its mentioned as default off heap is enabled by default. Is there any threshold before storing off-heap? How can i configure that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no offHeapMaxMemory property in CacheConfiguration since 2.0.

Yes, since version 2.0 by default caches store data in off-heap.
You can check it with:

`cache.size(CachePeekMode.OFFHEAP))`

But also, visor not properly counts "off-heap entries count" metric, but this is already fixed and will be available in version 2.1

Comment: In c++, is there any cache.size(CachePeekMode.OFFHEAP)) equvivalent?

Comment: yes, here is a link: https://ignite.apache.org/releases/2.0.0/cppdoc/classignite_1_1cache_1_1Cache.html#ae2a4bc2ff23bb72bd6338d3003c8d9f7

Comment: Does this size represent the off-heap or on-heap entries? What happens to the count, if OnHeapCacheEnabled is set to true?

Comment: Or it provides a total count? is separate metrics of the above available?

Comment: you need to invoke this method https://ignite.apache.org/releases/2.0.0/cppdoc/classignite_1_1cache_1_1Cache.html#ae2a4bc2ff23bb72bd6338d3003c8d9f7
with this argument: https://ignite.apache.org/releases/2.0.0/cppdoc/structignite_1_1cache_1_1CachePeekMode.html
If you will invoke it with CachePeekMode OFFHEAP, it will return size only for offheap